# DNN upgrade from 4.09.05 to higher version

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've been trying to upgrade DNN version 4.09.05 to 5.0.0. and higher but I always encounter errors in upgrading. Each version presents different errors. I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the vagueness of your posting, we aren't going to be able to help you much except point you to the Wiki for upgrade scenarios

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Upgrading-DotNetNuke.aspx

First things first, you should just attempt to upgrade from 4.9.5 to the latest 6.1.1 release, see if that works (after backing everything up)

Comment: Anyone who stumbles on this question. In the future I would recommend you upgrade to the latest release (as of this comment, 7.0.2)